# Why my android code is of large size?

Tags: android, android-camera

Following is the code for my app for a flash light

Its size comes out to be 1.4 MB which is too huge .

So i used progaurd to reduce size which ends up in 750 KB which is still huge as compared to code i am using.

Why the size is large ? and how to reduce it ? or i have made some mistake

```
package com.example.torch;

import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button power;
    int flag=0;
    public Camera camera;
    private boolean hasFlash;


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        try{

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        power=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);


        hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

        if(!hasFlash) {

            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
            alert.setTitle("Error");
            alert.setMessage("Sorry, your device doesn't support flash light!");
         alert.show();
           return;
           }

        camera = Camera.open();
        Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
        p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
        camera.setParameters(p);
        camera.startPreview();
        flag = 1;
        power.setText("Power On");
        power.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        power.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);



        power.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                      if (flag==0) {
                          camera = Camera.open();
                           Camera.Parameters p = camera.getParameters();
                          p.setFlashMode(Camera.Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
                          camera.setParameters(p);
                          camera.startPreview();
                            flag = 1;
                          power.setText("Power On");
                          power.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                        }
                       else
                    {
                        camera.stopPreview();
                        camera.release();
                        camera = null;
                        flag=0;
                        power.setText("Power Off");
                        power.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                      }


    }

});
    }
}
```

Comment: is ur .apk file is 1.4mb or whole file?

Comment: @W4R10CK whole file??

Comment: whole file means whole package/folder.

Comment: @W4R10CK 1.4 MB for apk only

Answer (score 2):

You are extending `AppCompatActivity`, this means that your project includes Android Support Library v7, if you don't care about material look on old Android versions, you can simply remove it. Check your `build.gradle` file to see which libraries are included as those libraries will make your apk file bigger.

Other causes of a large apk file might be:

- Drawables
- Assets